# Swap Control with Command on Apple Keyboard on Windows

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am Mac user at home, and I use Windows 7 at work. I sometimes work at home, I take my Windows laptop and plug in my Apple Keyboard. It works fine, except all shortcuts have to be invoked with Control key instead of Command (which maps to Windows key instead), so I could use Command+C, Command+V to cut&paste.

I'd like to remap modifier keys, so that:

- Pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> is interpreted as <kbd>Control</kbd>
- Pressing <kbd>alt/option</kbd> is interpreted as <kbd>Alt</kbd> (no change)
- Pressing <kbd>Control</kbd> is interpreted as <kbd>Windows</kbd>

**However**, I'd like this change affect only my Apple keyboard at home. I'd like my PC keyboard at work be unaffected.

I have tried MS Keyboard Layout Creator but it won't let me remap Control key.